# Java prints Japanese correctly in console but not in GLabel

Tags: java, unicode, graphics, character-encoding

When I print Japanese characters to the console, it works, but when I try to use them in a GLabel, it fails and gives a bunch of illegible characters. How can I fix this?

```
import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.program.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TestJapanese extends GraphicsProgram {

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("これはテストです");
        add(new GLabel("これはテストです", 100, 100));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestJapanese().start(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm actually amazed that that works in the source file.

Comment: GLabel ? do you mean JLabel or there is actually a GLabel i don't know of ?

Comment: Please do you homework yourself. GLable is a derivate of JLable, as specified by the University of Stanford: http://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/jtf/javadoc/student/acm/graphics/GLabel.html

Comment: You'll need to change the font used by the GLabel to something that can support the Japanese characters